# How to set print outputs equal to a variable in Java?

Tags: java

I'm new to Java and programming so if this question is painfully obvious for you I apologize in advance.

What I'm trying to do is set the printed output of a line equal to a variable so I can use that variable to add or subtract .3 depending on whether or not a "-" or "+" sign was typed in the input.

EDIT:

```
import java.util.*;
public class HomeworkCalculator {
public static void main(String[]args)
{ 
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
String grade, letter1, letter2;
System.out.print("Enter a letter grade: ");
grade = in.nextLine();
letter1 = grade.substring(0,1);
letter2 = grade.substring(1,2);

double gpa = 0;

if (letter1.equals("A"))
gpa = 3.9;
else if(letter1.equals("B")) 
gpa = 3.0;
else if(letter1.equals("C"))
gpa = 2.1;
else if(letter1.equals("D"))
gpa = 1.2;
else if(letter1.equals("F"))
gpa = 0;

System.out.println(gpa);

if(letter2.equals("+")) {
   System.out.println(gpa + 0.3);
} 

else if(letter2.equals("-")) {
System.out.println(gpa - 0.3);
}}}
```

So now the problem is if I just enter single letters A,B,C,D,F it gives me an error. Obviously I'd like this program to accept single-lettered grades in addition to defaulting the input of 'A+' to no higher than a 4.0, and making it so inputs like F+ or F- return the same gpa of 0 just like the grade F. I'll probably fool around with more if/else statements and logical operators..:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out   
of range
at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1907)
at HomeworkCalculator.main(HomeworkCalculator.java:10)
```

Comment: This code is legal (except that the `else if` at the beginning has to be part of an earlier `if`).  Whether it's what you want, I can't tell.  It's probably wrong that you're checking one variable (`plusMinusSign`) for `+` and a different variable (`letter`) for `-`.

Comment: You can check the typed input if it contains + or - and have if statements when it contains a + or another if when it contains a -

Comment: Don't be sorry. Just be clear in the first place. (Remember that nobody except you knows the context of what you're saying, nor the specific domain meanings of your terms.)

Comment: You still haven't clarified what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see multiple problems:

- `else if(letter.equals("-"))` but you means to test if `plusMinusSign.equals("-")`
- you start with `else if` instead of just `if`
- you hardcode a print result as `3.0` instead of using any variable.

Here's what I think you wanted to do (also remember to create variable `x` as lower case):

```
double x = 0; // or whatever you want x to initially be

if(letter.equals("B")) {
    x = 3;
}
System.out.println(x);

if(plusMinusSign.equals("+")) {
    // x = x + 0.3; // I don't know if you want to modify the variable
    System.out.println(x + 0.3);
} else if(plusMinusSign.equals("-")) {
    // x = x - 0.3; // I don't know if you want to modify the variable
    System.out.println(x - 0.3);
}
```

Comment: I am wondering what should be typed as input to make it work. B + ... ?

Comment: @Xbit I'm wondering that as well lol. The OP hasn't given us much to go on. I'm assuming that `letter` and `plusMinusSign` are strings (fair assumption) and he already has taken in the user input to get those strings.

Comment: Yeah sorry for the vague post, this is what I was trying to do. I figured I had to set my letter grades equal to a double but I didn't think about deleting all the "system.out.print's" from after I the if statements. I'll include an edit to the post showing my entire code.

Answer (score 1):

Considering `letter` and `plusMinusSign` are the `String` inputs. Consider assigning first and then printing the variable `X`.

Do it this way :

```
float X = 0.0f;
if(letter.equals("B")) {
    X += 3.0;
    System.out.println(X);
} else if(plusMinusSign.equals("+") {
    X += 0.3;                   // instead of System.out.print(X + .3);
    System.out.println(X);
} else if (letter.equals("-") {
    X -= 0.3;                   // instead of System.out.print(X - .3);
    System.out.println(X);
}
```

If you are trying to start with `else if` it won't work.
Try to go with this syntax:

```
if (...) {...}
else if (...) {...}  // There can be multiple `else if` statements
else {...}
```

Comment: Offhand it looks like you and the OP are trying to accomplish different tasks.

Comment: @ajb After I posted OP edited his question. I will edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: He also wants to check for + and -, i don't see this in your solution.

Comment: @Xbit I am editing it accordingly.

Comment: Why the downvote? It's as good an answer as any given the abstruse question.

Comment: @ajb corrected accordingly.

Comment: @Xbit corrected accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
String input;
double x = 0;

while((input = processInput()) != null) {
    if(input.equals("B")) {
        x = 3.0;
    } else if(input.equals("+")) {
        x += 0.3;
    } else if(input.equals("-")) {
        x -= 0.3;
    }
    System.out.println(x);
}
```

Comment: Remember, you're using `float`

Comment: Try to compile it lol

Comment: @mike - Thank you - making me boot up Eclipse at 2am instead of just being helpful. Grr.

Comment: Sorry - you would have to add an `f` to the end of the number (`3.0f`), or just change the type to `double`.

Comment: Also, you don't have to boot up Eclipse. You can go to http://ideone.com/ to run your code.

Comment: Now *that* is a useful tip!